# Problem running 'react-scripts start' from docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, docker

I like to use Docker as development environment and it worked quite well until react 2.1.8, but after upgrade the react to version 3.4.1, it stopped to work.

Now, the Docker container with the React application close with status exit 0, just after start the server.

It is strange because there is no log error. Any suggestion?

There is no error, just this log when I try `docker run react-frontend`:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

marcos@marcos-Inspiron-7472:~/Projetos/Virtus/Softex/edgeframework/maestro/frontend$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add stdin_open: true to the docker-compose file.

Comment: Thanks! this flag resolved my problem! Just an append, without docker-compose, the solution is `docker run -i react-frontend`